# WHERE DATE_COLUMN = '9999-12-31' statements causes query to return no results

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, db2, where-clause

I have a very odd problem with a query I was given to convert from Access to SQL Server.

The query works as expected until I add a condition in the WHERE clause to check for a specific date.

I was not sure that the date fields were compatible due to the SQL Server query needing to talk to a linked DB2 mainframe. So to test this to make sure the date is being read correctly I used `DATEDIFF()`. I also reduced the select statement to only the date field that is having the issue to try and figure out what is going on but I still have had no luck. I have tried ever way I can think of to filter the date.

I tried a `HAVING` clause.

```
HAVING TERM_DT = '9999-12-31'
```

I tried a `WHERE` clause.

```
WHERE TERM_DT = '9999-12-31'
```

I tried to compare the date in the `JOIN`.

```
INNER JOIN linked_db2_tbl11 tbl11
    ON tbl11.TERM_DT = '9999-12-31'
```

I tried to `CAST` and `CONVERT` the field to DATE thinking maybe the date fields were incompatible.

```
CAST(TERM_DT AS DATE) = CAST('9999-12-31' AS DATE)
CONVERT(DATE, TERM_DT) = CONVERT(DATE, '9999-12-31')
```

In each of the above I also tried `TERM_DT >= '9990-12-31'` because nothing else worked and for some reason that column has a few typos like `9998-12-31` and `9999-11-31` so I figured checking from `9990` on should catch everything. Still nothing returned.

The last thing I tried was `DATEDIFF()`. And that didn't work either.

```
DATEDIFF(day, '9990-12-31', TERM_DT) >= 0
```

Except when I placed the `DATEDIFF()` in the select statement and do not use anything in the WHERE section I get the values I expect...

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, '9990-12-31', TERM_DT) AS "DIFF"
,TERM_DT AS "DT"
FROM ...
JOIN ...
```

Data returned:

```
DIFF        DT
-2912352    2017-04-01
-2912261    2017-07-01
-2911852    2018-08-14
-2911852    2018-08-14
-2911624    2019-03-30
-2911624    2019-03-30
-2911532    2019-06-30
-2911532    2019-06-30
3287        9999-12-31
3287        9999-12-31
```

But when I add the where statement in:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, '9990-12-31', TERM_DT) AS "DIFF"
,TERM_DT AS "DT"
FROM ...
JOIN ...
WHERE DATEDIFF(day, '9990-12-31', TERM_DT) >= 0
```

I get no results:

```
DIFF        DT
```

Then I tried to flip the comparison with `<=` and the odd thing is I got all the values below `9999-12-31` as expected, so then why can I not get the values at `9999-12-31` to return? This is a very odd situation.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, '9990-12-31', TERM_DT) AS "DIFF"
,TERM_DT AS "DT"
FROM ...
JOIN ...
WHERE DATEDIFF(day, '9990-12-31', TERM_DT) <= 0
```

Oddly enough that worked as it should have:

```
DIFF        DT
-2912352    2017-04-01
-2912261    2017-07-01
-2911852    2018-08-14
-2911852    2018-08-14
-2911624    2019-03-30
-2911624    2019-03-30
-2911532    2019-06-30
-2911532    2019-06-30
```

So I can get the dates below `9999-12-31` but cannot get the dates at `9999-12-31`.
Once I realized that checking for dates lower than `9999-12-31` worked in the `DATEDIFF()` function I went back and tried to do my original comparison and check for those lesser dates. It worked...

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, '9990-12-31', TERM_DT) AS "DIFF"
,TERM_DT AS "DT"
FROM ...
JOIN ...
WHERE TERM_DT < '9999-12-31'
```

Results:

```
DIFF        DT
-2912352    2017-04-01
-2912261    2017-07-01
-2911852    2018-08-14
-2911852    2018-08-14
-2911624    2019-03-30
-2911624    2019-03-30
-2911532    2019-06-30
-2911532    2019-06-30
```

With the above results there is no reason for me to think that `WHERE TERM_DT = '9999-12-31'` would not return:

```
DIFF        DT
3287        9999-12-31
3287        9999-12-31
```

But I don't get that. I get no results at all.

Update:

I tried `DATEDIFF(day, '9990-12-31', DH230.DH230_TERM_DT) <> 0` as @[Ziad Mehmood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4303011/ziad-mehmood) mentioned and strangely I get all the negative values but none of the positive values.

```
DIFF        DT
-2912352    2017-04-01
-2912261    2017-07-01
-2911852    2018-08-14
-2911852    2018-08-14
-2911624    2019-03-30
-2911624    2019-03-30
-2911532    2019-06-30
-2911532    2019-06-30
```

2nd Update:

When I take my WHERE statement and move it to a CASE in the SELECT It clearly works. The Comparisons is correct. But just doesn't work in the WHERE section.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, '9990-12-31', TERM_DT) AS "DIFF"
,TERM_DT AS "DT"
,CASE WHEN DH230.DH230_TERM_DT >'2100-12-31' THEN 'True' else 'False' end
FROM ...
JOIN ...
```

Results:

```
DIFF        DT  (No column name)
-2911624    2019-03-30  False
-2911532    2019-06-30  False
-2912261    2017-07-01  False
-2912352    2017-04-01  False
3287        9999-12-31  True
3287        9999-12-31  True
-2911624    2019-03-30  False
-2911532    2019-06-30  False
-2911852    2018-08-14  False
-2911852    2018-08-14  False
```

So another shot in the dark I ran the CASE statement in the WHERE clause.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, '9990-12-31', TERM_DT) AS "DIFF"
,TERM_DT AS "DT"
FROM ...
JOIN ...
WHERE CASE WHEN DH230.DH230_TERM_DT >'2100-12-31' THEN 'True' else 'False' end = 'True'
```

But no results:

```
DIFF        DT
```

Now here is where it gets odd again:

```
WHERE CASE WHEN DH230.DH230_TERM_DT >'2100-12-31' THEN 'True' else 'False' end = 'False'
```

Returns:

```
DIFF        DT
-2912352    2017-04-01
-2912261    2017-07-01
-2911624    2019-03-30
-2911532    2019-06-30
-2911624    2019-03-30
-2911532    2019-06-30
-2911852    2018-08-14
-2911852    2018-08-14
```

Absolutely bizarre!

Is there some issue between SQL Server and a linked DB2 mainframe that could cause this?

Is there any know reason for something like this to happen?

I did create a local SQL Server table from a select statement to check the data type of the field.

The field is the DATE data type according to SSMS.

[image]

For a reference I have added my full query below with some obfuscation. Maybe something about the JOIN's is causing the problem.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, '9990-12-31', linked_db2_tbl11.linked_db2_tbl11_TERM_DT) AS "DIFF"
,linked_db2_tbl11.linked_db2_tbl11_TERM_DT AS "DT"

FROM local_database.dbo.local_table1 IR 
RIGHT JOIN linked_db2_tbl1
INNER JOIN linked_db2_tbl2
INNER JOIN linked_db2_tbl3
INNER JOIN linked_db2_tbl4
INNER JOIN linked_db2_tbl5
INNER JOIN linked_db2_tbl6
INNER JOIN linked_db2_tbl7
INNER JOIN linked_db2_tbl8
INNER JOIN linked_db2_tbl9 
ON linked_db2_tbl8.linked_db2_tbl8_SUB_SVC_TYP = linked_db2_tbl9.linked_db2_tbl9_SUB_SVC_TYP
INNER JOIN linked_db2_tbl10 
ON linked_db2_tbl9.linked_db2_tbl9_PACKAGE_ID = linked_db2_tbl10.linked_db2_tbl10_PACKAGE_ID 
ON linked_db2_tbl7.linked_db2_tbl7_PACKAGE_ID = linked_db2_tbl10.linked_db2_tbl10_PACKAGE_ID
INNER JOIN linked_db2_tbl11
ON linked_db2_tbl9.linked_db2_tbl9_SVC_TYP = linked_db2_tbl11.linked_db2_tbl11_SVC_TYP
AND linked_db2_tbl9.linked_db2_tbl9_PACKAGE_ID = linked_db2_tbl11.linked_db2_tbl11_PACKAGE_ID 
ON linked_db2_tbl6.linked_db2_tbl6_COMP_ID = linked_db2_tbl7.linked_db2_tbl7_COMP_ID 
AND linked_db2_tbl6.linked_db2_tbl6_COMP_ID = linked_db2_tbl11.linked_db2_tbl11_COMP_ID 
ON linked_db2_tbl5.linked_db2_tbl5_COMP_ID = linked_db2_tbl6.linked_db2_tbl6_COMP_ID 
ON linked_db2_tbl4.linked_db2_tbl4_ELEMENT_ID = linked_db2_tbl5.linked_db2_tbl5_ELEMENT_ID 
AND linked_db2_tbl4.linked_db2_tbl4_ELEMENT_ID = linked_db2_tbl11.linked_db2_tbl11_ELEMENT_ID 
ON linked_db2_tbl3.linked_db2_tbl3_ELEMENT_ID = linked_db2_tbl4.linked_db2_tbl4_ELEMENT_ID 
AND linked_db2_tbl3.linked_db2_tbl3_CHG_CD = linked_db2_tbl11.linked_db2_tbl11_CHG_CD 
ON linked_db2_tbl2.linked_db2_tbl2_CHG_CD = linked_db2_tbl3.linked_db2_tbl3_CHG_CD 
ON linked_db2_tbl1.linked_db2_tbl1_SUB_SVC_TYP = linked_db2_tbl8.linked_db2_tbl8_SUB_SVC_TYP 
AND linked_db2_tbl1.linked_db2_tbl1_HWIR_SVC_TYP = linked_db2_tbl8.linked_db2_tbl8_HWIR_SVC_TYP 
AND linked_db2_tbl1.linked_db2_tbl1_SVC_ID = linked_db2_tbl11.linked_db2_tbl11_LEVEL_ID
INNER JOIN linked_db2_tbl12
INNER JOIN linked_db2_tbl13 
ON linked_db2_tbl12.linked_db2_tbl12_RATE_PLAN = linked_db2_tbl13.linked_db2_tbl13_RATE_PLAN 
ON linked_db2_tbl1.linked_db2_tbl1_SVC_ID = linked_db2_tbl13.linked_db2_tbl13_SVC_ID
INNER JOIN linked_db2_tbl14 
ON linked_db2_tbl1.linked_db2_tbl1_UPPER_ID = linked_db2_tbl14.linked_db2_tbl14_CORP_ID 
ON IR.CHG_CD = linked_db2_tbl11.linked_db2_tbl11_CHG_CD 
LEFT JOIN linked_db2_tbl15 
ON linked_db2_tbl14.linked_db2_tbl14_CORP_ID = linked_db2_tbl15.linked_db2_tbl15_INT_ID
INNER JOIN linked_db2_tbl18
ON linked_db2_tbl1.linked_db2_tbl1_CNTL_LOCN_ID = linked_db2_tbl18.linked_db2_tbl18_COMS_LOCN_ID
JOIN local_database.dbo.local_table2 OT
ON linked_db2_tbl14.linked_db2_tbl14_CORP_ID = OT.CORP_ID
WHERE OT.USER_ID = 'SOMEID'
AND DATEDIFF(day, '9990-12-31', linked_db2_tbl11.linked_db2_tbl11_TERM_DT) >= 0
```

Comment: "Maybe something about the JOIN's or group by is causing the problem." Have you tried reducing to a simpler SQL statement that only touches the table containing this date field?

Comment: "due to the SQL Server query needing to talk to a linked DB2 mainframe." Does this mean that the actual data is not in SQL Server at all?  I imagine that could be an important point.  (But it would mean I have no help to offer.)

Comment: @DaveCosta yes I have. If I only touch that table the date comparison works just fine.

Comment: @DaveCosta some of the data is SQL Server. 2 tables to be exact. The rest is on the linked server.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use something like this?

```
where term_dt > '2100-01-01'
```

I'd be surprised if you had real dates even that far in the future.

Also, you have your arguments to `date_diff()` backwards, which is why the number is negative.

Comment: `where term_dt > '2100-01-01'` does not return any data. and `DATEDIFF()` I tried with both `DATEDIFF(day, '9990-12-31', TERM_DT)` and `DATEDIFF(day, TERM_DT, '9990-12-31')`.

Comment: The odd thing is that `where term_dt < '2100-01-01'` does return data...

Answer (score 0):

### Replication

```
Create Table [DateTest] (
    [date] date NOT NULL
)

insert into [dateTest] ([date])
values 
('2017-04-01'),
('2017-07-01'),
('2018-08-14'),
('2018-08-14'),
('2019-03-30'),
('2019-03-30'),
('2019-06-30'),
('2019-06-30'),
('9999-12-31'),
('9999-12-31')

SELECT DATEDIFF(day, '9990-12-31', dt.[Date]) AS "DIFF"
,dt.[Date] as [DT]
FROM [dateTest] as DT
```

---

### Diagnostic

When replication your statement (quoted), I ran the following:

> "But when I add the where statement in:"

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, '9990-12-31', dt.[Date]) AS "DIFF"
,dt.[Date] as [DT]
FROM [dateTest] as DT
WHERE DATEDIFF(day, '9990-12-31', dt.[Date]) >= 0
```

I retrieved the expected return:

```
DIFF    DT
3287    9999-12-31
3287    9999-12-31
```

The syntax for your SQL is correct, however there is possibly a datatype issue. Can you provide more information on the tables for querying?

---

### Request for further information

A simple case for the table definitions would be ideal, or just a simple row example of the 2 tables you want to join and the datatypes.

Its hard to replicate your question without knowing the exact definition of your access file. There are too many tables in the referenced script to isolate without a direct clone. By creating a simplified example, you may be able to resolve your issue.

---

### Recommendation

If this is a one time conversion from an Access based database, you can look at SSMS (Sql Server Management Studio) to use a direct import for access databases.

If you're looking for a way to schedule retrieval from a known Access file, what is the business requirement of using the Access file as opposed to a direct write to a SQL database? There may be a simpler solution to your issue.

Comment: *By creating a simplified example, you may be able to resolve your issue*... I tried that. I did a simple select from the table that contains the date field and that field accepted my where statement just fine. I copied out the SQL query and manually rewrote it to work from within SSMS. The query works without the WHERE clause just fine but only fails when I add the date condition. That said your condition is only working within SSMS. The table with the date field is in a linked server that is DB2.

Comment: I did do a `select linked_db2_tbl11_TERM_DT into LOCAL_TABLE from linked_db2_tbl11` and then check the data type within the design view of SSMS and it is data type of "DATE".

Comment: I dont have context for the DB2 definition, nor the definition for the Tables. 

Try and simplify your joins into clustered smaller joins. It will help with your diagnosis.

Personally, i'm a big fan of the "With" clause style, since it allows for easier diagnosis of sub-query issues. 

Can you provide a simple 3 table definition for the tables you want to join with some data examples? I'm guessing it may be an alias issue, or syntax issue and not a logistical issue.

Looking at the long query, there is a syntax issue in your select statement, and a few of your joins (missing commas).

Comment: Also none of this problem is related to `Access` I took a query that was in access and rewrote it in SSMS. The local tables are in the SQL Server and the other tables are a linked DB2 mainframe. So no Access is involved at this point.

Comment: There are no missing commas. One was missing from my example due to rewriting it for obfuscation reason. The query pulls all expected data without the WITH statement so I know the query is functional. I guess my only option is the try less and less joins until it works.

Comment: For example, a With Clause will look like: 
"
With SomeTable ([DateDiff], [Date])
as ( **Some select statement that has 2 columns**),
SecondaryTable([Col1Name],[Date])
as ( **some select statement with 2 columns ** )
select st.[DateDiff], secT.[Col1Name]
from SomeTable as st
join SecondaryTable as secT
on st.[Date] = secT.[Date]
"

Comment: Last i checked, Access SQL used Jet SQL or another variant of SQL 

While SQL server uses T-SQL. That may be the cause of this issue.

Answer (score -1):

Please try some thing like this as seen the data

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, '9990-12-31', TERM_DT) AS "DIFF"
,TERM_DT AS "DT"
FROM ...
JOIN ...
WHERE DATEDIFF(day, '2100-01-01', TERM_DT) <> 0
GROUP BY ...
```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: `<> 0` would get all results as thought I didn't write in a WHERE statement to begin with. Even if it worked it would not be the correct results.

Comment: Oddly enough `DATEDIFF(day, '9990-12-31',DH230.DH230_TERM_DT) <> 0` returns the same data as `DATEDIFF(day, '9990-12-31',DH230.DH230_TERM_DT) < 0` but does not return anything `> 0`. At least that tells me something. Doesn't solve the problem but tells me for some reason > values are being ignored for some odd reason.